# wGet - doc output stored as ASCI - want UTF-8

Tags: curl, encoding, utf-8, wget, ansi

H @ all,

looking for a way to tell wGet to store a downloaded CSV file in UTF-8 / UTF8 format instead of ANSI

Seems wGet decide a format automatically, but i don't now how to change this rule.

```
wget.exe --no-check-certificate --load-cookies="cookies.txt" --referer="http://10.11.3.2/Portal/Portal.mwsl?PriNav=Alarm" "http://10.11.3.2/Alarms/alarm.csv?ActLanguage=de" --output-document=../store/AlarmBuffer.csv
```

Right know this works fine for some different downloads, but fails on just one which is stored as an ANSI formatted document - should be UTF-8

Any ideas / recommendations?
If it would be possible with cURL, would also be ok for my needs :)

Thanks

Comment: Both wget and curl store the output in the form it was sent by the server. None of them convert the charset encoding on the fly for you.